# use nested IF in select query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use nested IF in part of select in query MySQL?

I do this, but It doesn't work

this is the code:

```
SELECT *, IF(`view_price_trp` <= 0 ,IF(`view_price_sgl` > 0,
(((`tour_package`.`view_dbl` * 2) + (`tour_package`.`view_sgl`)+
(`tour_package`.`view_dbl` * 2)) + ((`tour_package`.`price_b`))), NULL) ,
(((`tour_package`.`view_trp` * 3)+(`tour_package`.`view_dbl` * 2)) + 
((`tour_package`.`price_b`)))) As sumFieldPrice FROM `tbl_price`  WHERE 
((`tour_package`.`id` IN ('1420', '1421') HAVING (`sumFieldPrice` >= 10) AND 
(`sumFieldPrice` <= 1900) AND (`sumFieldPrice` <> NULL)
```

I Have question how can I achieve NULL in this query
I use it in having like this : (sumPriceField <> NULL) but after that, there isn't any return value

Is these query true? 
can we use nested if in MySQL?

Comment: Your query has errors far beyond anything to do with `if`.  For instance, `tour_package` is not defined.

Comment: why ? tour package is one of my table and my query don't have error without  IF, and my query is more  than I paste It here

Comment: Your WHERE clause starts with `((`, but only one of them is being closed. Please properly indent your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check NULL value by Operator. You can check it by using IS NULL in mysql. You need to replace

```
`sumFieldPrice` <> NULL
```

with

```
`sumFieldPrice` IS NOT NULL
```

I am considering if condition is closed properly as it's not closed properly here.

Comment: `<>`  is not the same as `IS`. I think you mean `IS NOT`